# Codebehind SQL Dropdown Webforms

Tags: c#, mysql, asp.net, webforms, code-behind

So I've been told I need to code to the Webforms standard of C#. The only tutorials I've been able to find seem very heavy on 'clicking and dragging' (which is bizarre to me coming from languages where you, well, type things out).

This seems to generate some code, but I'd like to understand the code it generates and I learn by example, so...

Can someone provide me a no-frills example using C# and a codebehind file of a connection to a MySQL database  "cheese" handled via a web.config connectionstring that dumps two columns "gouda" and "porridge" to two separate dropdowns?

Comment: what is so bad about drag and drop? you can achieve what you want without a line of code. I would personally do it programmatically when the logic is more complex. You can easily populate dropdown using the wizard.

Comment: I'd prefer to learn so that in future I can control things better when I need to.